# Binary Search Not Finding Certain Numbers

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search

I am building a binary number search. It aims to look through a range of ordered numbers to see if a given value is within it.

It is able able to find some numbers, but occasionally it will either enter an infinite loop or return False when the number is within the search parameters.

The code I currently have is:

```py
def binary_search(data_input, user_input):
    start_index = 0
    end_index = len(data_input) - 1

    while True:
        middle_index = int((end_index - start_index) / 2)
        if user_input > data_input[end_index] + 1 or user_input < data_input[start_index] - 1:
            return False

        if middle_index > end_index or middle_index < start_index:
            return False

        middle_element = data_input[middle_index]
        if middle_element == user_input:
            return True
        elif user_input > middle_element:
            start_index = middle_index
        else:
            end_index = middle_index


# I have used this loop to see which numbers create a problem
for i in range(12):
    x = 10
    data_in = np.arange(x)
    user_num = i

    print(user_num, binary_search(data_in, user_num))
```

The results from this particular loop are:

```
0 True
1 True
2 True
3 False
4 True
5 False
6 False
7 False
8 False
9 False
10 False
11 False
```

I cannot work out why this is happening. Pretty sure it is me being stupid, but if anyone can help I would really appreciate it!

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the rest of the algorithm, but the computation of the `middle_index` is incorrect:

```
middle_index = int((end_index - start_index) / 2)
```

For example, if `start_index = 5` and `end_index = 7`, the calculated `middle_index` is `1`, when it should be `6`.

For starters, then, you'll want to add the `start_index` to that range size calculation:

```
middle_index = start_index + int((end_index - start_index) / 2)
```

Comment: I agree with superb rain as I don't really understand what you mean. @fbrereto, would you be able to show me a code example?